# Build Fail: winsock2.h file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2, file-not-found

Added `#define _WINSOCKAPI_` but still the build is failing.

```
/*
 * $PostgreSQL: pgsql/src/include/port/win32/sys/socket.h,v 1.7 2006/10/04 00:30:10 momjian Exp $
 */
#ifndef WIN32_SYS_SOCKET_H
#define WIN32_SYS_SOCKET_H

/*
 * Unfortunately, <wingdi.h> of VC++ also defines ERROR.
 * To avoid the conflict, we include <windows.h> here and undefine ERROR
 * immediately.
 *
 * Note: Don't include <wingdi.h> directly.  It causes compile errors.
 */
#define _WINSOCKAPI_    //added this line but no help
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>

#undef ERROR
#undef small

/* Restore old ERROR value */
#ifdef PGERROR
#define ERROR PGERROR
#endif

/*
 * we can't use the windows gai_strerror{AW} functions because
 * they are defined inline in the MS header files. So we'll use our
 * own
 */
#undef gai_strerror

#endif   /* WIN32_SYS_SOCKET_H */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

`#ifndef __APPLE__ ... #endif`

Then, check out the other compile errors and include apple specific socket files, that also work under BSD socket.

Comment: Where should I put the above statement?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile a Windows-specific header file on a platform that is decidedly not Windows. I can't imagine what you expect this to do; whatever it is, though, it doesn't.

Comment: I am trying to import a existing project.

Comment: So leave that file out. Also: If the project is PostgreSQL, it's intended to be built from the command line, not from XCode.